# How many states to be associated with an Order entity?

Tags: object-oriented-design, domain-driven-design, domain-model

I am currently adding functionalities to Order Entity and have a column storing the state of the current order in **Status**.

Order goes through the following workflow with minor deviations I have not captured for keeping this simple:

`Placed -> Payment -> Inventory procurement -> Shipped -> Delivered OR Cancelled`

So my order status currently looks like

```
public enum OrderStatus{
   PLACED, PAID, INVENTORY_PROCESSED, SHIPPED, DELIVERED, CANCELLED
}
```

*Delivered* and *Cancelled* are the terminal states here.
There could be a lot of steps in between, like for example when a payment is tried for and fails.

Should I go about storing granular states like *Payment Initiated*, *Payment Failed* at the order status or let the APIs be deriving this exposed if someone wants to add a functionality upon this.

Point in favour of having granular states at Order:

- Keeps everything observable by just looking at the Order Entity and lets others easily use this.

Point against granular states:

- At some point state transitions might become too complicated to arrive at and comprehend and to what number these states can go.

What are the best ways to think about this or if possible mention your experiences/references.

Apologies if this is not the right forum to ask this, which if the case is, please redirect me to a place where this would fit best.

Comment: It is a totally "business analyst in software" decision. It asks for a trade-off between two heavy costs: on one side, it almost feels like certainty that more functionality (states) will need to be added in the future (but we just don't know what it should be today), on the other side, there will be software development cost associated with complexity and making changes. It would be nice if people could point to examples of how other companies decide to implement (categorize) these things, and their thinking process behind that.

Comment: Beware of potential possibility of overlaps between applicable state-labels. For example, for certain types of customers (e.g. VIP or resellers), inventory processing may start before the payment is confirmed. There are many kinds of such overlaps.

Comment: The "state" in this case is merely a human-readable label that helps end-users quickly understand (describe) the situation of a transaction, and to make it easier to index (to search for the transaction in a database). But, because the true business state can be rather complex (it is a timeline log of transaction events e.g. payment confirmed, address confirmed, user has initiated a cancellation request, package rejected by delivery service, etc), from the database side it is these events that need to be searchable. The simple "state label" is merely a convenience.

Comment: The "state-label" also determines how an end-user-facing application (e.g. a mobile shopping app) should display relevant information to user. It is the "mode" (as in "modal") that the app will be when the user opens the app when a transaction is in process. In this regard, the state label would be a decision to be made by the UX designer.

Comment: Starting to look it your way, the state does seem to be a human-readable label. It definitely helps someone who is coding against your entity to be presented with that information. 
My question is then, let's say if your entity exposes very few or no states at all. Should the client which in this case can be any microservice or even a sub module query for things like if the "order was tried for payment". Or should a guideline be established to put common questions as a label ?

Comment: @user3757331, is there currently a business need to request the list of orders that were tried for payment? Or would the business start with a set of payments and want to retrieve the corresponding orders?

Answer (score 0):

If these sub-states are NOT too many, consider adding another column `substate` besides your existing `state` column. So readability is also not lost and additional information is also stored.

If these sub-states are just so many that continuously updating them will hamper the bandwidth of disk/network IO, consider using a log/events database. MongoDB can also be used here, https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/use-cases/storing-log-data. Although I feel this is highly unlikely to be needed.

If it helps, please note that in my experience, designing for far future has always been worse than not designing for the near future. If you cannot enlist a future unmanageable list of sub-states today, better go ahead with saving them in a separate column for now.

Comment: Performance is not much of a concern as manageability is in this case. How should one go about deciding what to put as a sub state and what not? As user rwong has pointed out in one of his comments, what if the user places a request for cancellation meanwhile the order was out for a shipment with a certain sub state of its own , how should we capture if at all this in a substate. Any ideas would be great to hear.

Comment: For that we need to understand what would be the business handling in this case.

Comment: Are you going to allow our not. If yes, that becomes a reverse workflow. Cancelling delivery, cancelling inventory booking, payment reversal, etc. In this case you would need another flag marking an order as "Cancel Requested". After this your app should start the reverse workflow.